# Sum based on pattern match for multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have an excel input data like below

```
purchase revenue          FY_1920   FY_2021 FY_2122
PID21 kids & adults (KA)    75        75     80
PID21Elderly and old (EO)   75        75     80
PID76Men or boys            80        75     80
PID52 Women or ladies       100       25     100
Total                       330       250    340
```

which looks like below

[image]

Now, I would like to fill the below `output` table based on below logic

Fill in `cars` row based on keywords `PID21 and PID24` of input table

Fill in `Electric Vehicle` row based on values of keywords from `PID43, PID76, PID152` of input table

criteria table looks like below

[image]

I was trying something like below with the help of online support

```
SUMIFS(C$21:C$25, $B$21:$B$25, INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, LARGE(IF(Sheet1!$B:$B = Input!$B5, ROW(Sheet1!$B:$B), ""),1))
```

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Comment: Do you define these PID for car types? Do you have any other table for these keyword?

Comment: How excel will know which `PID` for which type of cars? What is your actual excel version? You have tagged 2010 & 2019.

Comment: @Harun24hr - Yes, I define these PIDs. It is in another table.

Comment: My excel version is 2019

Comment: You should be able to sum up with SUMIFS but using as criteria wildcars. Something like `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5;$B$2:$B$5;"PID21*")` will sum up values in a column based on another column **starting** with the text PID21. If your PIDs are constant and not change, you may use it

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - How do I key in multiple PIDs in wildcars? Should I repeat the same formula that you wrote multiple times (depending on no of PIDs)?

Comment: In order to be helped with a solution, "Yes, I define these PIDs. It is in another table." statement is at least strange... Please edit your question and show the sheet you are talking about. I will give more eloquence to your question. Is it there equivalences between these 'PIDs` and categories in column B:B?

Comment: So write versions for PID43, PID76, PID152 or just use the numbers 43, 76 if they are unique. Have a go at testing as you have been given a flexible solution.

Comment: updated the post with how criteria table looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your PIDs criteria a few and do not change, you may use several SUMIFS combined:

[image]

for `cars` output formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C5;$B$2:$B$5;"PID21*")+SUMIFS(C$2:C$5;$B$2:$B$5;"PID24*")
```

for `electric` formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C$5;$B$2:$B$5;"PID43*")+SUMIFS(C$2:C$5;$B$2:$B$5;"PID76*")+SUMIFS(C$2:C$5;$B$2:$B$5;"PID52*")
```

Notice both formulas got first argument with mixed references, so you just need drag to right the formula.

**UPDATE**: Now that i saw you got your PID's somehwere else, I would suggest you to use this structure:

[image]

Notice the PID'S at most right are not using combined cells (that's a terrible idea because it affects formulation). So first you get in your data what kind of BL is with:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2;5);$I$2:$J$6;2;FALSE)
```

Then you do again SUMIFS but based on that column, so much easier:

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C$5;$A$2:$A$5;$B10)
```

Just drag to right and down and you'll get all output!

Comment: nice. will try now. Just a question out of curiosity to learn excel. So, can this problem be solved any better/faster using macro? Or formula is the best for this problem?

Comment: @TheGreat please, check updated answer

Comment: Only problem is in my real data, we cannot have `A` column like what you have got due to strictly formatted sheets etc (i can't modify that). Nonetheless, I will use your 1st solution.